# Primes and boolean logic

Tags: java, boolean, primes, boolean-logic

I wanted to write a program to find all the primes from b to a so I wrote this code (which worked):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int a;
    int c;
    boolean isPrime;

    a = 2;
    c = 0;

    while(a <= 100000 ){
        isPrime = true;
        for (int b = 2;b<a; b++){
            c = a%b ; 
            //System.out.println(c);

            if ( c == 0){
                // this stores every not prime number
                isPrime = false;                            
            }                           
        }

        if (isPrime){
            System.out.println(a);
        }           
        a=a+1;  
    }                                   
} // main end
```

Next I tried to write a variation of this code, which did not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int q;
    int w;
    boolean isPrimeOne = false;

    q = 2;
    w = 0;

    while(q <= 100){
        isPrimeOne = false;
        for (int d = 2; d<q; d++){                      
            w = q%d;
            if( w != 0 ){
                isPrimeOne = true;
            }                                               
        }   
    }

    if(isPrimeOne){
        System.out.println(w);
    }

    w = w+1;
}
```

It seems to me like my first and second codes are very similar. The only difference (I see) is that I initialized `isPrime` as `true` in the first one, and as `false` in the second one.

Why does the first code work and the second does not?

Comment: You are incrementing `w` in the second one instead of `q`.

Comment: Even if it was `q`, it is actually incremented outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 code examples are similar, but they are opposite in the initializations and handling of the `isPrime` and `isPrimeOne` variables.

The first code assumes that a number is prime (`true`) until a factor is found.  That proves the number is composite, so it's set to `false` and it stays that way until the loop finishes.  Just one factor is needed to prove that it's composite.

However, the second code assumes that a number is composite (`false`) until a number is found that isn't a factor.  But just because a number was found not to be a factor doesn't mean that it's prime.  E.g. `20` doesn't have `3` as a factor, but it's still composite.  You are printing `w`, the remainder, instead of `q`, the number you're testing.  You are incrementing `w` instead of `q`, and that is outside the `while` loop instead of inside the `while` loop.

Comment: There doesn't exist an `n` such that `P(n)` is not the same as there exists an `n` such that `¬P(n)`. [Negation of Quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#Negation). Fun topic.

Answer (score 0):

Four problems here:

- you are incrementing `w` instead of `q`;
- you are incrementing it outside the `while` loop (check you matching curly braces);
- you have inverted the logic for `isPrimeOne` with respect to `isPrime` in every assignment but not in the check for printing the number, so you are outputting something only for non-prime numbers;
- you are outputting `w` instead of `q`.

I suggest that you reduce the scope of your variables as much as possible, there is no need to declare all variables at the beginning of the method. If you declare `w` and `isPrimeOne` inside the `while` loop, this will prevent you from trying to use them elsewhere by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

"It seems to me like my first and second code are very similar. the only difference (I see) is that I initialized is prime as true first, and is prime as false second."

Well actually not. There are more differences in those two programs. Just do a simple compare of each line and you'll find them out.

"why does the first code work and the second code not work"

Because the first program follows a valid algorithm for finding out prime numbers. The second program does not follow any such algorithm. For details see rgettman's answer.